# Using Python (Pygame, Pynput or something else) to write serial data to Arduino to control servos

Tags: python, arduino, pygame, pyserial, pynput

First, I am very new to Python, but I am trying to write a Python program to write serial data to my Arduino for the purpose to control servos. I am basically wanting my computer’s keyboard to act as a controller for the servos. The process would go something like this:

1. Once a key is pressed, the servo would start moving a certain direction.
2. If the key is held, the servo would continue moving
3. Once the key is released, the servo would stop moving.

I have tried using Pygame and Pynput, but I can’t get it to work. I have been using Pyserial to connect to the Arduino.

Any related questions already on here, help, or other links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/10649208/ help?

Comment: Sort, but I am not sure he/she is using keyboard input to then write to the arduino. I need to look more into it though.

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way is to use basic serial I/O.**

I use this kind of setup for my data-loggers that occasionally need the Arduino to take action based on the data or the clock.

EXAMPLE:

Assuming that you want to use a USB port (like on a RPi3), say you want to send a command that will cause the Arduino to emit two long beeps.  (Or it could trip relays, whatever) the code would look something like this:

**PYTHON SIDE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
```

First open up the port:

(Often as shown, but for CHG340 Arduinos will be more like `/dev/ttyACM0`)

```
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
```

To read from the port, use:

```
linein = ser.readline()
```

To write to the Arduino use:

```
ser.write("A")
```

**ARDUINO SIDE, (remembering that it will arrive as type `char`)**

In setup()

```
char cTMP;
int beePin=12;

Serial.begin(9600);
while (Serial.available()>0) cTMP=Serial.read();  // flush the buffer
```

Then somewhere in loop()

```
if (Serial.available) > 0) {
    if (serIn=='A') {
      digitalWrite(beePin,HIGH); delay(2000); digitalWrite(beePin,LOW);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(beePin,HIGH); delay(2000); digitalWrite(beePin,LOW);
    }

}
```

**I tend to stick to single-letter commands to the Arduinos**

---

The beauty of this setup is that you can also run the Arduino IDE on the RPi3 for Arduino programming, and you can use VNC or `xrdp` (with Windows Remote Desktop or remmina) to access it remotely.

I call it a Piduino.

Comment: Yes, I plan to use something like that to control the servos. The biggest issue is taking keyboard input and then ser.writing that. How could I get it to send an “a” to the arduino when I press a on my keyboard and then send another “a” when I release it